# Maven shade plugin is not creating "src/main/resources" directory,but it is placing the files directly under root

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am building uber jar with Maven shade plugin. But the jar has config/properties files directly in root instead of under "src/main/resources". Any help is appreciated on how to troubleshoot it ?

Tried by adding the below section in pom, but no luck

````
   <build>
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        </resources> ```
````

Comment: The full pom file would help here....and the directory structure you are using?...

Comment: The plugin will not create the directory `src/main/resources` as no other plugin will create `src/main/java` etc. You have to create it on your own..And the configuration you have given is not needed?